# ¿Se puede, a partir de un observable en angular, hacer un .map (o algún otro método) y obtener un arreglo con solo una propiedad?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Buenos dias soy nuevo en angular y tengo una consulta: Estoy usando un observable para recuperar una llamada al método http get, es decir estoy consumiendo un API, pero la cuestión es que estoy haciendo un CRUD y necesito hacer una comparación para saber si el ID que estoy registrando ya está en la base de datos, entonces quisiera saber si es posible aplicar un `.map` al observable para solo obtener la propiedad del ID y obtener un nuevo array con solo esta propiedad y de ahí hacer la lógica necesaria.

Este es mi código donde paso los dos parámetros al subscribe del observable, la variable 'res' seria la que esta almacenando el array con los objetos, y es la que desearia aplicarle el .map,pero no puedo llamar dicha variable fuera de dicha funcion. Si hay otro metodo o forma de hacerla me gustaria muchsimo que me ayudaran.

```
RenderDataTable() {   

  this.service.getAllEquipos().subscribe(  
    res => {  
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();  
      this.dataSource.data = res;  
    //  console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    //  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; 
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       console.log(res)          
    },  
    error => {  
      console.log('Se produjo un error mientras intentaba recuperar Usuarios!' + error);  
    });

}
```

El resultado ( es decir el array con solo los ID de ese observable) lo usuaria en la siguiente función que esta en un componente( ventana modal para editar/ crear un nuevo registro), y que es una funcion que se ejecuta apenas le da al boton enviar

```
onSubmit() {

  if (this.service.EquipoForm.valid) {

    if () { // Linea donde debo hacer mi logica para saber si voy a crear o 
        editar mi registro en cuestion, basado en si el ID esta ya creado o 
         no // 

      this.service.createEquipo(this.service.EquipoForm.value).subscribe();
    }
    else {
      this.service.updateEquipo(this.service.EquipoForm.value).subscribe();
    }
    this.service.EquipoForm.reset();
    this.service.initializeEquipoFormGroup();
    this.success('Registro Enviado con Exito');
    this.onClose();
   }
 }
```

Estoy intentando retornar el array con solo una propiedad del objeto completo mediante el operador:

```
    return this.http.get<Equipos[]>(this.baseurl + 'equipos').pipe(map( 
      data => {
        return data.id_equipo
      }
```

pero la ultima linea, me aparace el siguiente error:

La propiedad 'id_equipo' no existe en el tipo 'Equipos[]'

donde Equipos[] es una interface

```
export interface Equipos {

  id_equipo: number;
  nombre: string;
  vendedor: string;
  ip_gestion:string;
  tipo: string;
  localidad:string;
  categoria:string;
  ultima_actualizacion:string;

}
```

Comment: Hola Cesar, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla y conocer el sitio. No me queda claro lo que quieres conseguir, pero existe el operador `map` para aplicar a las resoluciones de los observables. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo usarías el resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejemos claro primero que la clase Observable no es de Angular, sino de una librería que Angular usa llamada [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs).

Las últimas versiones de RxJS han pasado de usar métodos en la clase Observable a usar [*operadores*](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators), funciones independientes que hay que importar aparte y que se usan *dentro* del método [`pipe`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#pipe-). Uno de estos operadores es `map`:

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const miObservable = of({a:1, b:'texto'});
miObservable.subscribe(dato => console.log(dato));

const otroObservable = of({a:1, b:'texto'});

const mapeado = otroObservable.pipe(
  map(dato => {
    return dato.b; //nos quedamos sólo con el campo b
  })
);
mapeado.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.0.0/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Por tanto podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const elementosEnBD = [
 {id:1, b:'texto1'},
 {id:12, b:'texto2'},
 {id:33, b:'texto3'}
];

const mockHttpGet = () => of(elementosEnBD);

function estaEnBD(id) {
  return mockHttpGet().pipe(
    map(lista => { //lista es un array de elementos, miramos si alguno concuerda
      for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (lista[i].id === id) {
          return lista[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    })
  );
}


estaEnBD(12).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.0.0/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok Pablo gracias, acabo de actualizar la publicacion y error que sale cuando intento returnar el map del observable

Comment: Pablo en mi caso la funciion mockHttpGet seria el objeto observable? Porque hay es donde me queda la duda segun mi codigo